# Exoplayer HLS slow to switch up quality

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to figure out how to make my exoplayer implementation switch up to a higher quality stream. Lowering the minimum time to switch up on the chunk source has not worked. I have been finding that it takes like 5 seconds to get higher quality while on reliable WiFi.